# Polymorphism in Callablle under python type checking (Pylance)

Tags: python, type-hinting, typechecking, pylance

For my code I have an aggregate class that needs a validation method defined for each of the subclasses of base class `BaseC`, in this case `InheritC` inherits from `BaseC`.

The validation method is then passed into the aggregate class through a register method.

See the following simple example

```
from typing import Callable


class BaseC:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
class InheritC(BaseC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, c:'InheritC') ->bool:
        return False

class AggrC:
    def register_validate_fn(self, fn: Callable[[BaseC], bool])-> None:
        self.validate_fn = fn

ac = AggrC()
ic = InheritC()
ac.validate_fn(ic.fn)
```

I added type hints on the parameter for registering a function, which is a Callable object `Callable[[BaseC], bool]` since potentially there will be several other validation methods which is defined for each class inherited from `BaseC`.

However, pylance doesn't seem to recognize this polymorphism in a `Callable` type hint and throws a warning (I set up my VScode to type check it) that said

```
Argument of type "(c: InheritC) -> bool" cannot be assigned to parameter "fn" of type "(BaseC) -> bool" in function "register_fn"
  Type "(c: InheritC) -> bool" cannot be assigned to type "(BaseC) -> bool"
    Parameter 1: type "BaseC" cannot be assigned to type "InheritC"
      "BaseC" is incompatible with "InheritC" Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

I don't see where I made an mistake in design, and I don't want to simply ignore the warning.

Can any one explain why this is invaid?
Or is it just simply a bug from pylance

I'm using python version `3.8.13` for development.

Comment: Without checking myself, I suspect the issue is that `InheritC::validate` is incompatible because it doesn't just take one `BaseC`-compatible parameter, it also takes the class `cls` parameter. I _believe_ that a free-standing function, called `validate`, which _only_ takes the `BaseC`-compatible object as a parameter, would work.

Comment: I haven't checked, but you might also want to try removing the `@classmethod` decorator, and just declaring the method as `def validate(self: 'InheritC'): return False`, then passing _that_ to the `register_validate_fn`. I assume the examples are stripped down from a real application; you're not calling `register_validate_fn` before calling `validate_fn`, but I assume you meant to.

Comment: Sorry to keep responding, but... there's another bug in the sample code: `ic.fn` is not defined. I'll start working on an answer with what I _think_ the sample is supposed to read like.

Comment: I was wrong about the method parameters - the problem is more subtle, I'll write a full answer because it's a fairly abstract problem.

Comment: Sorry, the `ic.fn` is my initial naming of the function. I renamed it for better readabilaty on stack overflow but I forgot to change all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be using the below sample code, where I've fixed a couple of bugs:

```py
from typing import Callable


class BaseC:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

class InheritC(BaseC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, c:'InheritC') ->bool:
        return False

class AggrC:
    def register_validate_fn(self, fn: Callable[[BaseC], bool])-> None:
        self.validate_fn = fn

ac = AggrC()
ic = InheritC()
ac.register_validate_fn(ic.validate)
```

This Python *runs* without errors, but still produces the same error you're seeing when run through a type checker (in my case, MyPY):

```
$ mypy stackoverflow_test.py 
stackoverflow_test.py:21: error: Argument 1 to "register_validate_fn" of "AggrC" has incompatible type "Callable[[], bool]"; expected "Callable[[BaseC], bool]"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This is a subtle issue, which is easy to overlook: it's an issue with [contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) of parameter types.

The reason this is easy to overlook is because most object-oriented tutelage focuses on classes and objects, and doesn't really discuss *functions* as being types with inheritance. Indeed, most languages with object-oriented language features don't support declaring a function as inheriting from another function!

Lets reduce this as much as possible:

```py
from typing import Callable

class Parent:
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def bar(self):
        pass
    
def takesParent(parameter: Parent):
    parameter.foo()
    
def takesChild(parameter: Child):
    parameter.bar()
    
def takesFunction(function: Callable):
    # What should the signature of `function` be to support both functions above?
    pass
```

How should you define `function: Callable` to make it compatible with *both functions?*

Lets take a look at what `takesFunction` could do, which would be valid for both functions:

```py
def takesFunction(function: Callable):
    child = Child()
    function(child)
```

This function should work if you pass either function, because `takesParent` will call `child.foo()`, which is valid; and `takesChild` will call `child.bar()`, which is also valid.

OK, how about this function?

```py
def takesFunction(function: Callable):
    parent = Parent()
    function(parent)
```

In this case, `function(parent)` can only work with `takesParent`, because if you pass `takesChild`, `takesChild` will call `parent.bar()` - which doesn't exist!

So, the signature that supports passing both functions looks like this:

```py
def takesFunction(function: Callable[[Child], None]):
```

Which is counter-intuitive to many people.

The parameter function must be type-hinted as taking the *most specific* parameter type. Passing a function with a *less specific* parameter - a superclass - is compatible, but passing one with a *more specific* parameter isn't.

This can be a difficult topic to understand, so I'm sorry if I didn't make it very clear, but I hope this answer helped.

Comment: It seems that this is rather a design problem, I looked again on my code and realized it is better to just simply do the validation during the construction of the base class `BaseC`, no need to double check on the aggregate class, according to the information expert principle.

Comment: The type-check is working as designed. There's another material more than wiki link: [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) explains why and [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#subtype-relationships) has an example.